# Create comma separated array using each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I create list of IP address with comma separated when using each loop?

```
ip_list = [];
hostnames.each do |host|
  puts host.ip  
end
```

I tried `ip_list.join` but that isn't working at all. I want all the host IP in a variable with comma seperated.

I want the output to be comma separated string.

Example:

```
puts ip_list
10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.11
```

Comment: What's `hostnames`? Can you add what that variable holds?

Comment: hostnames is a database query. It has IP, name, id etc. I want to pick only IP and create a comma separated list. It prints IP correctly for each host but I just need to create a list

Comment: There is no *comma separated list* in Ruby :) What do you mean? What's your input? What's expected output? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73518966/edit) your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? You can use [Array#push](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Array.html#method-i-push).

```rb
ip_list = [];
hostnames.each do |host|
  ip_list.push host.ip  
end
p ip_list
```

Or, `Array#map` would be more useful.

```rb
ip_list = hostnames.map { |host| host.ip }
p ip_list
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked to use `each` but why not use `collect`?
This gives you an array:

```rb
hostnames.collect(&:ip)
```

If you want a comma-separated list do:

```rb
hostnames.collect(&:ip).join(',')
```

If you need conditions in the iterator, you can use the longer block syntax:

```rb
hostnames.collect { |host|
  next unless host.name.match(/some_regex/)
  host.ip
}.compact # b/c otherwise you'll end up with some nil entries
```

Comment: This. Internalising the functional programming concepts map/filter/reduce will get you very far. Less mutable state and fewer if/else constructs, too.

Comment: Need to use each loop because I have conditions in the loop.

Comment: What do those conditions look like?

Comment: @Robert you can include conditions in the `collect` iterator. I used a shorthand syntax, but I edited my answer to show the longer syntax, with conditions

Comment: You could use `each_with_object` to avoid `compact`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get new array based on the existing one and filter by condition at the same time, you can use `filter_map` (was introduced in Ruby 2.7)

If you wan to get string from array just use `join`

```
hostnames.filter_map { |hostname| hostname.ip if some.condition }.join(", ")
```